# Excel, VBA: How to use Autofilter with multiple range selection

Tags: excel, vba

I want to activate filters for selected columns only. But when using this code to set filters to columns C, D, G and H I get an error:

```
Range("C1:D1,G1:H1").AutoFilter
```

> Run-time error '1004'
>
> This can't be done on a multiple range selection.
>
> Select a single range and try again.

But it is a must for me to filter only SOME columns and not all.

Does anybody know the answer?

Comment: This is unfortunately not possible. Try doing it manually; you'll get the same error.

Comment: Can you tell us why you need the filter activated on those columns only? Perhaps you may activate the filter for the row and then hide the columns to achieve what you're aiming for? PS: it's virtually impossible to filter a database partially (like what would happen with the column values?) So either you copy and paste the columns that you desire to a new sheet or store them somehow on memory and display only the required fields when filtering

Comment: If you don't mind use a Userform, (depends on how is your data table) maybe you can get what your want by creating four comboboxes, each is populated from unique value in column C, then populate next combox with unique value in column D (after it;s being filtered) and so on.